# Model rounded chair

Tags: modeling

For a project I need to model a chair that looks like this:

[image]

I don't know where to start, can someone show the right direction?

Comment: This BSE site is not a tutorial site for particular projects. Its quite interesting how you have a close vote even though no words were written to you.  Welcome to BSE. Some people lose their patience when human beginners ask for tutorials which might be considered beyond beginners.  You are a human are you not? This site has learning resources which you can request.  Youtube has many tutorials.  Please see this entire video tutorial series. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS

Comment: Once you have seen many tutorials please show your Blender work in a screen capture.  Then your question will not be a tutorial request.

Comment: Bonne Chance. Happy Blender.

Comment: Even if you showed some cylinders and spheres arranged nicely in addition to your image that would be an improvement.

Answer (score 3):

As Atomicbezierslinger told you, your question is too vague. I just tried the wooden cage part, you can do it with a circle that you extrude, then cut in half, then *Array* around with an empty as *Object Offset*. Then you choose a cube as *Boolean* to cut it off.

[image]